# Retrieving the image and then modify the image (adjusting colour etc..)

Tags: android

I am making an app for retrieving the  image and then modify the image. So when doing the project in eclipse how can i virtually create an sd card in eclipse and also put some sample images to it.?Also can someone please mention any good source for retrieving images frm sd card ,modify it and then again save it to sd card?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Eclipse in `Window| AVD Manager` create AVD with an SD card.
Then in DDMS perspective you can see the contents of that SD card in `File Explorer` tab.
You can also push/pull files to/from this virtual SD card.